# Selecionar somente uma parte do titulo do DataFrame

Tags: python, funções, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Imaginem a seguinte situação, eu tenho um DataFrame com nome qualquer. 
Dentro desse DataFrame eu possuo colunas com os seguintes titulos Mais(abc), Menos(abc), Sub(abc), seguindo dos dados de cada coluna. 
O nome abc é referente aos dados de abc, tenho também Mais(dfg), Menos(dfg), Sub(dfg).

Como eu crio uma função que mantenha os dados de cada coluna, mas na hora de printar esse dados eu altero o nomes das colunas somente para abc ? Ou seja removendo Mais, Menos e Sub.

Assim o resultado seria abc mais os dados e dfg mais os dados, removendo o Mais, Menos, Sub e também os ().

Comment: Recomento você por código que já tem para que alguém possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 2):

Se fizemos o seguinte:

```
import pandas as pd
dicio = {"Mais(abc)":[1,2,3],"Menos(abc)":[4,5,6], "Sub(abc)":[7,8,9], 
         "Mais(dfg)":[10,11,12], "Menos(dfg)":[13,14,15], "Sub(dfg)":[16,17,18]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dicio)
```

A tabela em df será

```
    Mais(abc)   Menos(abc)  Sub(abc)    Mais(dfg)   Menos(dfg)  Sub(dfg)
0   1           4           7           10          13          16
1   2           5           8           11          14          17
2   3           6           9           12          15          18
```

Para renomear as colunas então façamos o seguinte:

```
new_columns_names = ['abc', 'abc', 'abc', 'dfg', 'dfg', 'dfg']
df.columns = new_columns_names
```

A saída será:

```
    abc         abc         abc         dfg         dfg         dfg
0   1           4           7           10          13          16
1   2           5           8           11          14          17
2   3           6           9           12          15          18
```

Answer (score 0):

A melhor forma para resolver esse problema é usando `regex` (expressões regulares):

```
import re

df.rename(columns=lambda x: 
             re.search(r"\((.*?)\)", x).group(1) if re.search(r"\((.*?)\)", x) else x)
```

EDIT:

Neste caso a expressão `\((.*?)\)` faz a seguinte pesquisa:

`\(` - Procura a abertura de parêntesis

`(.*?)` - Primeiro grupo de captura (ou seja, tudo o que está dentro de parêntesis)

`\)` - Procura o fecho de parêntesis

Comment: Adorei sua resposta, eu estava tentando mesmo usar expressões regulares, mas estou começando e ainda acho difícil de entender.

Comment: Sim, pode ser algo complicado de início. Vou editar a resposta para explicar como esta expressão faz a procura.